# Ability to add tag to favorites/ignore list within tags

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, ignored-tags

It would be nice to be able to immediately add a tag to your favorites or ignore list, from the tag itself (by dropdown, context menu or even drag and drop).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is already available! Just hover on any tag, you will get option to toggle the tag between favorite, ignored and normal.

> [image]

Comment: Silly me for not seeing that... thanks!

Comment: The only problem with this (imo) is that when ignoring, it ignores only `tag`, and not `tag*`, which is what I prefer... so back to square 1 for me!